# Удалить li из ul | делегирование

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events, делегаты

```js
/*
  Дан ul, а внутри него произвольное количество li с текстом и кнопкой. 
  Сделайте так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, удалялся тот li в котором
  она находится. Используйте делегирование.
*/

let list = document.querySelector('.list');
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function removeItem(){
  target = event.target;
  
  if(target.nodeName == 'BUTTON'){
    
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>HTML</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>CSS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>JS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>React</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>NodeJS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>PHP</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

нужно удалить всю li, нижимая на кнопку внутри нее

Answer (score 1):

Для старых браузеров не забыть [полифилл](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

```js
document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
    event.target.closest('li').remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>HTML</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>CSS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>JS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>React</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>NodeJS</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Delete</button>
    <span>PHP</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ссылочку на полифилл для стрелочных функций?

Comment: @Igor, в вопросе уже используется let, так что я предположил, что код уже собирается бабелем (если это вообще требуется). А вот полифиллы для DOM сами собой не подключатся.

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к ответу:

```
let list = document.querySelector('.list');
let btn = document.querySelector('li');
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function removeItem(){
  target = event.target;

  if(target.nodeName == 'BUTTON'){
    target.parentNode.remove(target);
  }
}
```

Comment: Не очень, потому что код легко поломается при изменении разметки.

Comment: `target.parentNode.remove(target);` - у метода `remove` нет параметров